# Map coordinates of a matrix to number of samples unequal to length of one matrix line

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm trying to map items from a list to coordinates of a matrix. A pair of rows in the matrix should hold the same items, but with different suffixes. If the remaining number of items is less than the length of the row, the mapping should fill the row accordingly and then continue in the next row.

Here is what I came along for now:

```py
my_list = ['Item {}'.format(i) for i in range(30)]

# Create matrix of 8 rows and 12 columns and coordinates
rows = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
columns = range(1, 13)
coordinates = [row + str(column) for row in rows for column in columns]

# Map items to coordinates, with each pair of rows (A & B, C & D, etc.) holding
# the same items, but with two different suffixes (e. g.)
suffixes = ['_one', '_two']
full_rows = len(my_list) // len(columns) * len(suffixes)
remaining_items = len(my_list) % len(columns)

for i in range(full_rows):
    for j in range(len(columns)):
        if i % len(suffixes) == 0:
            suffix = suffixes[0]
        else:
            suffix = suffixes[1]
        coordinate = rows[i] + str(columns[j])
```

The above's code works to create the coordinates and assign the suffixes correctly. However, the items from `my_list` are still missing. I was thinking about determining an index within the loop. Something like simply counting up `index = j + len(columns) * i` will not work, as every second row will be the same items as the one before.

I'm somehow stuck. Thus, I would be happy, if someone has input what I'm missing here or what to look at.